# How to get the next line of file if pattern match in file using Perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to find pattern `Pattern String` , once it found , I need to get the next line of pattern, which contains page number, I need extract the page number `2` in below sample text file `Page: 2 of 5`. Here is my try:

```
my $filename="sample.txt";
$i=1;
open(FILE, "<$filename") or die "File couldn't be matched $filename\n";
@array = <FILE>;
foreach $line(@array){
chomp($line);
if ($array[$i]=~/(\s+)Pattern String(\s+)/) {
    if ($array[$i]=~/(\s+)Page:(\s+)(.*) of (.*)/) {
        $page = $3;
    }
}
```

Here is my sample text file :

```
                                    Pattern String

MCN: 349450A0     NCP Account ID: 999 600-0089           Page: 2 of 5
=============================================================================
Customer Name:    PCS HEALTH SYSTEMS

Customer Number:  349450A0
```

Comment: Where did `$i` come from?

Comment: $i value is 1 , Sorry I have edited the code now.

Comment: I am new to Perl, So please anyone tell me how to extract the value of next line after the pattern matched..

Comment: What is your expected output and what are you trying to achieve from your code?

Comment: I am trying to find pattern 'Pattern String' , once it found , I need to get the next line of pattern , which contains page number, I need extract the  page number '2' in above example 'Page: 2 of 5'

Comment: It's not the next line, the next line is empty.

Comment: Ok , I want page number in next available line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? Is that what you want? After a match and if next line is not empty then show the line. Let me know if worked for you.

```
# Perl:
my $filename="sample.txt";
my $match = undef;
my $line = "";

open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "Failed to open file: $!";

foreach (<$fh>) {
 $line = $_;
 if ( $line =~ /.*Pattern\sString.*/ ) {
  $match = 1;
  next;
 } 
 if (($match == "1") && ($line !~ /^$/)){
  print $line;
  $match = undef;
 }
}
```

Comment: With this approach you don't have to load entirely sample file into memory, hence reducing the memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve the problem (I'm assuming that the sample files will always have the same format). I hope this will help you, please let me know if it worked.

```
my $filename="sample.txt";
my $count = 0;
my $tgline = 0;

open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "Failed to open file: $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;

foreach (@lines) {
 if ( $_ =~ /.*Pattern\sString.*/ ) {
  $tgline = $count + 2;
  if ( $lines[$tgline] =~ /.*Page\:\s(\d+)\sof\s(\d+)$/ ) {
   print "Current page: " . $1 . "\n";
   print "Total page #: " . $2 . "\n";
  }
 }
 $count+=1;
}
```

Comment: How to get the next available line after pattern match dynamically  without giving count number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you matching `Pattern String`, if your target is achieveing `2` from `Page: 2 of 5` from your input file. This is a way to get this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = "sample.txt";
open my $fh, "<","$filename" or die "Couldn't open $filename: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    if($line =~ m/.*Page:\s(\d+)\sof\s(\d+)$/)
    {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

sample.txt:

```
                                    Pattern String

MCN: 349450A0     NCP Account ID: 999 600-0089           Page: 2 of 5
=============================================================================
Customer Name:    PCS HEALTH SYSTEMS

Customer Number:  349450A0
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I want pattern matching along with above answer